# What's the meaning of "consult admins"?

Tags: grammatical-number

When we're told:

> Please consult admins before you post any comments.

Knowing that there are 2 admins, does the sentence above mean we should consult both of them, or is it enough to consult one of them, please?

Comment: It means any one of them.

Comment: In real life, 'get in touch with an administrator'. In logic classes, 'consult at least 2 of the administrators'. There, they don't worry about pragmatics (here, how people often assume a meaning other than the logical one, and this may be the default sense) or Gricean restrictions (2? 3? 17? Grice would say 'insufficient information given, so this reading is suboptimal.)

Comment: It means you should use any procedure that is considered appropriate to consult with the admins. If permission from a single admin is sufficient to proceed, speak to one; if you need permission from all of them, you'll have to consult them all. Generally, if only one admin was required, you might say "consult an admin", but if you regard the admins as a single group, any of whom can be consulted, you might say "consult admins" plural. It's the same as "Buy vegetables for dinner" - what you need to buy depends on what you're cooking.

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically there is a group of people, "admins" that you need to consult. It isn't specified how you consult with that group, whether you need to consult all or just some or one. It depends entirely on context. The same grammar would be used however many you have to consult.

Practically speaking talk to one of them and they will know if you need to talk to the other.

Answer (score 0):

The exact procedure is not made clear.  For example, "consult admins" may require you to send an email to "admins@example.com" (while you only need a response from one admin) It may require you to speak in person to all the admins or it may just be badly written, and mean "consult with one or more admins".

You can't infer details of the procedure from vague instructions.